# Flutter chat app: How to find out if notification has to be shown or not?

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, chat

I'm using fcm in a flutter chat app. The chat app has different channels the user can subscribe to. If the user is subscribed he will get fcm notifications for new messages in the channel even if the app is open. The notifications are sent out on a topic which is named like the channel id.
Now of course I don't want to show the user the notification if he has the channel open where the new message is appearing (because he is seeing it anyway).
How could I go about finding out if I have to show the notification or not?

I handle the notification in the onMessage callback function. My idea was to find out which screen the user is seeing or which route he is on, but as far as I have researched, there is now way to use the Navigator to find out the current route that the user is on. My only other idea would be to somehow save the current channel the user is seeing in a global state and then checking it in the onMessage callback before showing the notification but this seems very hacky...

Answer (score 1):

Flutter's MaterialApp has a route observer that can be used to make a widget route aware. A widget can subscribe to route changes and when displayed react to what is the current route. Using this, you can make some widgets route aware and should be able to subscribe/unsubscribe to FCM topics based on what route the user is currently on. At least it's something worth looking at.

```
 // Register the RouteObserver as a navigation observer.
final RouteObserver<PageRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Container(),
    navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
  ));
}

class RouteAwareWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  State<RouteAwareWidget> createState() => RouteAwareWidgetState();
}

// Implement RouteAware in a widget's state and subscribe it to the RouteObserver.
class RouteAwareWidgetState extends State<RouteAwareWidget> with RouteAware {

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didPush() {
    // Route was pushed onto navigator and is now topmost route.
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    // Covering route was popped off the navigator.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container();

}
```

For more information see [RouteObserver](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html)

Looking at the tests for [Route](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/widgets/routes_test.dart) and [Navigator](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/widgets/navigator_test.dart) can also be helpful.